# SMTP Connection DNS Connection Redirect

Tags: domains, dns, email, mx

If I had a domain such as example.com and an smtp address for a mail server such as really.long.smtp.address.com is it possible to setup a DNS record on example.com, such as smtp.example.com, and to make this redirect any SMTP connections on to really.long.smtp.address.com?

This way, when I add the SMTP login details in to a mail client and set the server to smtp.example.com, it would connect and work?

Comment: Redirects are an HTTP construct. Not SMTP. Not DNS. So no. Not even in your dreams. You can, however, alias one domain to another using CNAME.

Comment: @closetnoc I see - do you know if this practice is RFC-compliant?

Comment: @closetnoc wouldn't it work to set up the MX record for smtp.example.com and the an A record for smtp.example.com pointing to the IP address of really.long.smtp.address.com

Comment: @Steve Not sure. You are on the right track. I would use CNAME. The caveat would be the SMTP sever. Many require knowing the domain name the service sits on and then you configure it for the domain names it answers for. It may be that the service requires an exact match for the domain name of the MX record.

Comment: @PaulF See my comment above. I do not see the purpose of doing what you suggest. I would not do it. Cheers!!

Comment: I used to be a web host. Here is an example. SMTP.example.com hosts the SMTP server. An MX record exists for example.com pointing to SMTP.example.com. that would be required for the service configuration. I add newexample.com to the SMTP server. I would then create an MX record for newexample.com pointing to SMTP.example.com or possibly to SMTP.newexample.com where a CNAME exists pointing SMTP.newexample.com to SMTP.example.com. Clear as mud?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?   Is this so email clients can be configured to send outgoing mail through a different service?   Or is this so that incoming mail gets delivered to a different service?